# Setting up a utility class and using it within a vue component

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

A vue application I am working on currently has lots of code redundancies relating to date functions. In an effort to reduce these redundancies, I'd like to create a utility class as shown below, import it and set it to a Vue data property within the component, so I can call the date functions within it.

I am not certain on the best way to implement this. The current implementation results in an error saying `TypeError: this.dates is undefined` and my goal is not only to resolve this error but create/utilize the class in the Vue environment using best standards.

Importing utility class

```
    import Dates from "./utility/Dates";
...
```

Component

```
const contactEditView = Vue.component('contact-edit-view', {
        data() {
            return {
                contact: this.myContact
                dates: Dates
            }
        },
...
```

Dates.js

```
export default {
    dateSmall(date) {
        return moment(date).format('L'); 
    },
    dateMedium(date) {
        return moment(date).format('lll');
    },
    dateLarge(date) {
        return moment(date).format('LLL');
    }
};
```

View

```
Date of Birth: {{ dates.dateMedium(contact.dob) }}
```

Comment: Why are you setting it as data? Why not setting it up in the methods section or just importing it for use.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean, can you provide an example?

Comment: `const contactEditView = Vue.component('contact-edit-view', {
        data() {
            return {
                contact: this.myContact
            }
        },
        methods: {
            dateSmall: Dates.dateSmall,
            dateMedium: Dates.dateMedium,
        }
})`

Comment: I don't want to have to do that. I'd like to have all date functions available within the view without setting one by one.

Comment: Then don't do it, my point was to not use data to do this as the goal of data is to be observable property. `methods: { Dates: Dates}̀` should work. Or you could just import the module to be in scope for your components, it does not have to live inside of vue

Comment: @Axnyff `methods: { Dates: Dates }` will not set the method definitions correctly. And if you want to reference methods inside a Vue template, they do need to be set on the Vue component.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend You shouldn't be getting that error based on the code you've provided. Do you call `dateMedium` anywhere else? Or could you show a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @thanksd, you're right, the error I am getting is `TypeError: this.dates is undefined`, I've edited the OP to reflect this.

Comment: Your code wouldn't produce that error either... Are you calling `this.dates` somewhere else?

Comment: The code IS producing this error and no, I am not.

Comment: The main focus here is to use the these date functions within the scope of a particular vue component, so any approach that can accomplish this using good standards, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163805/discussion-between-thanksd-and-anchovylegend).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My suggestion for this is to use a plugin option in Vue. [About Vue plugin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

So you will crate a new folder called **services**, add file **yourCustomDateFormater.js**:

```
const dateFormater = {}

dateFormater.install = function (Vue, options) {

   Vue.prototype.$dateSmall = (value) => {
     return moment(date).format('L')
   }
   
   Vue.prototype.$dateMedium = (value) => {
     return moment(date).format('lll')
   }
}
```

In **main.js**:

```
import YourCustomDateFormater from './services/yourCustomDateFormater'

Vue.use(YourCustomDateFormater)
```

And you can use it anywhere, like this:

```
this.$dateSmall(yourValue)
```

---

Or, if you want to use mixin. [Read more about mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

Create a new file dateFormater.js

```
export default {
  methods: {
    callMethod () {
      console.log('my method')
    }
  }
}
```

Your component:

```
import dateFormater from '../services/dateFormater'

  export default {
    mixins: [dateFormater],
    mounted () {
      this.callMethod() // Call your function
    }
  }
```

**Note**: "*Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every single Vue instance created, including third party components. In most cases, you should only use it for custom option handling like demonstrated in the example above. It’s also a good idea to ship them as Plugins to avoid duplicate application.*" - Vue documentation

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I like this idea, although what if I don't want to use it everywhere, but just within the components I specify?

Comment: In other words, what if I'd like to import these functions within the scope of a particular component.

Comment: In that case you can use Mixin - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Please note:
Use global mixins sparsely and carefully, because it affects every single Vue instance created, including third party components. In most cases, you should only use it for custom option handling like demonstrated in the example above. It’s also a good idea to ship them as Plugins to avoid duplicate application.

Comment: I have recurring functions in various areas. I'd like to define these functions once and 'plug in' these functions ONLY to the components I specify. Is this possible?

Comment: Yep, you can use mixin :)

Comment: Can you edit your answer / provide an example on how I would define such a mixin in an external file and then import it in to the component above and include it as a mixin? Then I can accept your solution as an answer, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you check it now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, mixins is what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @Latovic Nice! I was looking for a service instead... ;p

Answer (score 1):

dateUtilsjs

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

function formatDateTime(date) {
    return moment.utc(date).format("M/D/yyyy h:mm A")
}

export { formatDateTime }
```

Component JS

```
...
import { formatDateTime } from '../utils/dateUtils'
...
methods: {
    formatDateTime,
}
```

Used within component

```
{{ formatDateTime(date) }}
```

Comment: Yo this is clutch - even though it's not what I was looking for